# centos: Another MySQL daemon already running with the same unix socket

Tags: mysql, sockets, unix, centos6

I have a strange error when starting mysqld service:

```
Another MySQL daemon already running with the same unix socket.
```

I've tried to list running services and stopping them but the same error happens when starting mysqld service.

I can try to remove the mysqld and reinstall it but will this remove the database too?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

<s>To prevent the problem from occurring, you must perform a graceful shutdown of the server from the command line rather than powering off the server.</s>

<s># shutdown -h now</s>

<s>This will stop the running services before powering down the machine.</s>

Based on Centos, an additional method for getting it back up again when you run into this problem is to move mysql.sock:

```
# mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak

# service mysqld start
```

Restarting the service creates a new entry called mqsql.sock

Comment: The second recommendation above worked for me.  Must have happened because I did not shutdown the server gracefully.  Doing a `# reboot` did not solve the problem.  Never tried the `shutdown -h now`

Comment: "shutdown -h now" and boot did not solve it for me but the "CentOS" option worked like a charm.

Comment: Perform the `# mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak` then `# shutdown -h now` and it should come up fine.

Comment: Moving the sock file worked for me as well.

The big question I have is **how** this happened.  I've never seen this problem before.

Comment: Does anyone know how this problem could have occurred?

Comment: axiom82, it usually happens if the server is shut down forcefully, either by powering off suddenly, or by shutting down without first stopping the running services.

Comment: I always use `shutdown -r now` so it turns back on. Am I supposed to do: `shutdown -r -h now`?

Comment: You can run into this problem if you're doing a server migration using rsync. The solution above won't help in that case. I'm doing some test migrations using some VMs and I didn't find a solution for this problem yet.

Comment: Works by just moving the file, without shutting down.

Comment: The first part of the answer looks nonsense to me. -h flag has nothing to do with "graceful shutdown" or shutting down the services before reboot, as this should be a default shutdown behaviour. Answer most likely gets upvoted because of it's second part.

Comment: @IlliakaillI I wrote this reply back in 2014 when the -h flag still meant something. It's no longer required.

Answer (score 19):

### TL;DR:

Run this as root   and you'll be all set:

```
rm $(grep socket /etc/my.cnf | cut -d= -f2)  && service mysqld start
```

---

### Longer version:

You can find the location of MySQL's socket file by manually poking around in `/etc/my.conf`, or just by using

```
grep socket /etc/my.cnf | cut -d= -f2
```

It is likely to be `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.  Then (as root, of course, or with `sudo` prepended) remove that file:

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then start the MySQL daemon:

```
service mysqld start
```

Removing `mysqld` will not address the problem at all.  The problem is that CentOS & RedHat do not clean up the `sock` file after a crash, so you have to do it yourself.  Avoiding powering off your system is (of course) also advised, but sometimes you can't avoid it, so this procedure will solve the problem.

Comment: The `cut -d= -f2` bit might appear wrong, because you'd expect a value to appear after the `=` sign, but the `=` *is* the value passed to the `-d` option: in other words, `=` is used as the delimiter for `cut`.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, try replacing `/etc/my.cnf` with `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: I'd suggest greping something more specific then any line containing the word _socket_, at least `grep '^socket[[:space:]]=' /etc/my.cnf`, or you may end up deleting something you didn't intend.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution for anyone in this problem
change the socket dir to a new location in my.cnf file

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock
```

and `service mysqld start`

or the fast way as GeckoSEO answered

```
# mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak

# service mysqld start
```

Comment: I just deleted the mysql.sock file and then restarted the service.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this was a left over mysql.sock in the /var/lib/mysql/ directory from a hard shutdown.
Mysql thought it was already running when it was not running.

Comment: yeah you are right I made shutdown to the system then this problem arises , so you have a solution when I start server not to show this error

Answer (score 2):

Just open a bug report with your OS vendor asking them to put the socket in /var/run so it automagically gets removed at reboot. It's a bug to keep this socket after an unclean reboot, /var/run is the spot for these kinds of files.

Answer (score 1):

in order to clean automatically .sock file, place these lines in file /etc/init.d/mysqld immediately after "start)" block of code

```
test -e /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
SOCKEXIST=$?

ps cax | grep mysqld_safe
NOPIDMYSQL=$?

echo NOPIDMYSQL $NOPIDMYSQL
echo SOCKEXIST $SOCKEXIST

if [ $NOPIDMYSQL -eq 1 ] && [ $SOCKEXIST -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "NOT CLEAN"
    rm -f /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    echo "FILE SOCK REMOVED"
else
    echo "CLEAN"
fi
```

it worked for me. I had to do this because I have not an UPS and often we have power supply failures.

regards.

Comment: The above is the way to go since it happens out of our control that power goes out and UPS dies after a while. So the server must recover. I have this problem on a mysql 5.7 (centos 6) installation but not on a 5.1 (centos 5). I don't have time to investigate what is wrong with the first one so I'm just gonna improve on this answer and use that.
    test -e $socketfile
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

Comment: looks like it took me more than 5 min to prepare the pastebin: here it is https://pastebin.com/DpiSGrmh

Answer (score 1):

It may sometime arises when MySQL service does not shut down properly during the OS reboot.
The /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock has been left. This prevents 'mysqld' from starting up.

These steps may help:

1: service mysqld start
killall -9 mysqld_safe mysqld
service mysqld start

2: rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
   service mysqld start

Answer (score 0):

To start the MySQL service, you can remove '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' and start the MySQL service again:

Remove the socket file:

```
[root@server ~]# rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
rm: remove socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'? yes
```

Start the MySQL service:

```
[root@server~]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

It will help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just happen because of abnormal termination of mysql service. delete or take backup of /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file and restart mysql.

Please let me know if in case any issue..

Answer (score -1):

I just went through this issue and none of the suggestions solved my problem.  While I was unable to start MySQL on boot and found the same message in the logs ("Another MySQL daemon already running with the same unix socket"), I was able to start the service once I arrived at the console.

In my configuration file, I found the following line: `bind-address=xx.x.x.x`.  I randomly decided to comment it out, and the error on boot disappeared.  Because the bind address provides security, in a way, I decided to explore it further.  I was using the machine's IP address, rather than the IPv4 loopback address - `127.0.0.1`.

In short, by using `127.0.0.1` as the `bind-address`, I was able to fix this error.  I hope this helps those who have this problem, but are unable to resolve it using the answers detailed above.